# How to hover an absolute element within a relative one?

Tags: css

I've got an icon 'X' that shows in corner of button when button is hovered. Problem is I can't click on it for some reason, like element doesnt even exist.  Here is html:

```
<button *ngIf="favapps.indexOf('qualitydocs') >= 0" (mouseover)="showQualitydocs = true" (mouseleave)="showQualitydocs = false" class="btn btn-sq btn-primary text-center"
     [routerLink]="['/dokumenti-kvalitete']">
     <i class="fa fa-file-text-o inside fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     <br>Dokumenti
     <br> kvalitete
     <span class="relative-qualitydocs"><span class="absolute-qualitydocs" *ngIf="showQualitydocs" (mouseover)="showQualitydocs = true" (mouseleave)="showQualitydocs = false"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></span></span>
</button>
```

and css:

```
         .absolute-qualitydocs {
            z-index: 100;
            position: absolute;
            top: 22px;
            background: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #67809F;
            padding: 0 3px;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #67809F;
            &:hover {
                background-color: #d1d1d1;
            }
        }
        .relative-qualitydocs {
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
            left: -67px;
            top: -67px
        }
```

As you can see on the picture it shows correctly, but I cant click on it, I cant hover it, even `cursor: pointer` doesn't work. Any ideas what might be wrong? Tried putting `z-index` and `display: block`, didn't help.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Could you recreate this using e.g. JSFiddle – first of all it will be easier to help, but also you might be able to find the problem by yourself. I think the markup you provided isn't enough

Comment: What is the chance that you can create a **working** demo such as http://plnkr.co/ or something.

Comment: failing to do so since i never used it before.

Comment: @MoshFeu this might help? https://codepen.io/dragolj/pen/oyWMWx

Comment: just realised it works when parent element is 'span' and not 'button'...

Comment: @Kerim092 so you good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by putting 'span' ('div' also works) as a parent element instead of 'button' ... if anyone has a clue why this happens, please share cause i have no clue... here is [working pen](https://codepen.io/dragolj/pen/oyWMWx)

```
<button class="parent-relative">  <!-- doesnt work -->
  <span class="child-absolute"></span>
</button>

<span class="parent-relative"> <!-- works -->
  <span class="child-absolute"></span>
</span>
```

css:

```
.parent-relative {
  position:relative;
  padding: 200px;
  background: red;
  margin:50px;
}

.child-absolute {
  position:absolute;
  padding:20px;
  background:yellow;
  cursor:pointer;
  top: 0;
  left:-40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML and CSS

```css
.delete-hover {
        z-index: 100;
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #67809F;
        padding: 0 3px;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #67809F;
    }
    .delete-hover:hover {
           background-color: #d1d1d1;
     }
    .relative-qualitydocs {
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

   .absolute-qualitydocs {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: -18px;
   }
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-sq btn-primary text-center relative-qualitydocs">
 <i class="fa fa-file-text-o inside fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 <br>Dokumenti
 <br> kvalitete
 <span class="delete-hover absolute-qualitydocs" *ngIf="showQualitydocs" (mouseover)="showQualitydocs = true" (mouseleave)="showQualitydocs = false">&times;</span>
</button>
```

Comment: nope,tried that but it doesnt help, and plus delete-hover/absolute-qualitydocs has to have absolute position, thats why its wrapped in relative element (so i can position it on corner of button which can be moved, and to not influence elements within a button).

Comment: Didnt exactly work but i like that you did with it. For some reason, it works when parent element is 'span' and not 'button'.. check it yourself https://codepen.io/dragolj/pen/oyWMWx

Comment: may be some other css on your page is affecting it. coz for me it works fine with the button tag also :(

Comment: sorry i am not on my pc right now. will check and get back to you